# Distinguish clicks from mouse_event with hardware clicks

Tags: c++, windows, click

My goal is to make a program that auto-clicks when the user mouse button is pressed down.

At this moment, I have this.

```
while (true)
        {
            Sleep(1);
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON))  

                 {


                    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);




                }
                Sleep(delayy);
```

But when I use this it just starts a loop, because the program will keep detecting the clicks and keep sending more inputs.
How can I resolve this?

Comment: You want a program which "auto-clicks" *what*? What is the *real* problem your program is supposed to solve?

Comment: As for your problem, how about a simple flag telling your program to call `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)` or not?

Comment: @Some programmer dude I want something that sends continuous clicks when the user's left mouse button is held. This is meant for games.

Comment: Unless you want to send the clicks to yourself, perhaps what you really want is something like [`SendMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) to send click to a specific window?

Comment: I think this will not work because it needs to have a very low delay. Someone said something about Mouse Hooks to me, but I can't understand the documentation.

Comment: The only way to distinguish between genuine and injected input is to use a [low-level mouse hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986.aspx). Besides that, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event) **explicitly** tells you to not call `mouse_event`. Anyway, downvoted for lack of research. Questions about implementing some sort of autoclicker come in at a steady rate of approximately one per week.

Answer (score -1):

To determine if a button or key is pressed down you can use this:

```
if((GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x100) != 0)
```

For the code you are looking, you can try the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)) {

                keybd_event(VK_LBUTTON, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
                while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON))
                {
                    keybd_event(VK_LBUTTON, 0x45, 0, 0);
                    std::cout << "Click" << std::endl;
                }
        }

        Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

This might need some optimization and fix but you can sort it out in your code.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Comment: @IInspectable as mentioned, it does provide some insight on what he might try to accomplish what the OP was asking

Comment: The only potential insight this proposed answer contains is to use [GetKeyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate). But you cannot use this API call here. Read the documentation to learn why. This answer provides no information on how to distinguish between genuine and injected input. And that is, what the question is asking for.